# keras cnn_lstm input layer not accepting 1-D input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have sequences of long 1_D vectors (3000 digits) that I am trying to classify. I have previously implemented a simple CNN to classify them with relative success:

```
def create_shallow_model(shape,repeat_length,stride):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(75,repeat_length,strides=stride,padding='same', input_shape=shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(repeat_length))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

However I am looking to improve the performance by stacking an LSTM/ RNN on the end of the network.

I am having difficulty with this as I cannot seem to find a way for the network to accept the data.

```
def cnn_lstm(shape,repeat_length,stride):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(75,repeat_length,strides=stride,padding='same', activation='relu'),input_shape=(None,)+shape))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(repeat_length)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(6,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model=cnn_lstm(X.shape[1:],1000,1)
tprs,aucs=calculate_roc(model,3,100,train_X,train_y,test_X,test_y,tprs,aucs)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (50598, 3000, 1)
```

My questions are:

1. Is this a correct way of analysing this data?
2. If so, how do I get the network to accept and classify the input sequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add those `TimeDistributed` wrappers. Currently, before adding the LSTM layer, your model looks like this (I have assumed `repeat_length=5` and `stride=1`):

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 3000, 75)          450       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 600, 75)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 45000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 45001     
=================================================================
Total params: 45,451
Trainable params: 45,451
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

So if you want to add a LSTM layer, you can put it right after the `MaxPooling1D` layer like `model.add(LSTM(16, activation='relu'))` and just remove the `Flatten` layer. Now the model looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_4 (Conv1D)            (None, 3000, 75)          450       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 600, 75)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 16)                5888      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 6,355
Trainable params: 6,355
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

If you want you can pass the `return_sequences=True` argument to the `LSTM` layer and keep the `Flatten` layer. But only do such a thing after you have tried the first approach and you have gotten poor results, since adding `return_sequences=True` may not be necessary at all and it only increases your model size and decreases model performance.

---

As a side note: why did you change the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in the second model? There is no need to do that since `binary_crossentropy` would work fine.

Comment: Hello, why are the timedistributed wrappers not necessary?  Every source says that to apply the convolution to every element in the sequence you need the wrappers, but you do not for LSTM because it is made to consider the time element of a sequence.

Comment: @user1723196 Because the OP has clearly stated in their question: "I have sequences of long 1_D vectors (3000 digits) that I am trying to classify" Therefore, each input sample is just a sequence of 1D vectors. Wrapping `LSTM` or `Conv1D` layers in a `TimeDistributed` layer only makes sense when **each input sample** consists of **multiple sequences**, e.g. each input sample is hourly weather temperature of 30 days in a month where each day has its own separate sequence (each input sample would have a shape of `(30, 24, 1)`, i.e. it's a 3D tensor).

Comment: Okay.  Thank you.  This was very helpful.  I have a similar situation and following others' suggestions did not work.  It does run without timedistributed wrapper, and I just wanted to verify that was the correct way to do things.  I appreciate you, today.